# Запуск консольного приложения двойным кликом по файлу

Tags: c, файлы, консоль, exe

Есть файлы являющиеся консольными приложениями Win32 написанные на C. При попытке запуска файла двойным кликом по нему приложение выполняется и консольное окно тут же сворачивается. Как этого избежать?

> getchar();

дописанный в конец программы позволяет открывать их правым кликом и пунктом Открыть из выпадающего списка, двойным кликом они не открываются, но открываются тройным. Как запускать эти файлы обычным двойным кликом?

Comment: Извините, ни за что не поверю, что добавление вызова `getchar()` делает exe-файл не запускаемым двойным щелчком... Что-то вы не договариваете.

Comment: Каким боком тут вообще `C`? Уверяю, программы, которые написаны на паскале, ассемблере или перле ведут себя точно так же.

Comment: А вообще консольные программы надо запускать из консоли :)

Comment: Проэкспериментировал, без гетчара окно сворачивается всегда, не помогает ни тройной клик, ни правая кнопка с пунктом открыть контекстного меню, если getchar(); перед return 0; то помогает тройной клик и правая кнопка с пунктом открыть контекстного меню. Если getchar(); после return 0; то двойной клик работает, но так вроде не надо делать? Компилятор ругается

Comment: Вроде два гетчара перед ретюрн помогают, но полностью не уверен

Comment: Еще раз и медленно. Итак, вы скомпилировали программу без `getchar()`. В Проводнике двойной щелчок запускает ее, и она быстро отрабатывает и закрывается. Теперь вы компилируете ее с `getchar()`, после чего запустить ее в проводнике двойным щелчком невозможно, а только выбором в контекстном меню пункта открыть? Так? О в этом контекстном меню пункт "Открыть" выделен полужинным (ну, пункт по умолчанию)? Если нет - а должно быть нет, потому что иначе у вас приложение бы запускалось - то что там выделено полужирным?

Comment: У меня большое подозрение, что вы что-то недопонимаете, и соответственно вводите в заблуждение нас... `getchar()` просто останавливает выполнение программы в ожидании ввода с нажатием клавиши Enter, и никак не связано с количеством кликов для запуска...

Comment: У вас [случаем не стоит какая-нибудь клавиатурная приблуда](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows7/thread951982.html)?

Comment: PinkTux  "А вообще консольные программы надо запускать из консоли :)" Это не так просто, для начала команда start ищет только файлы в папках path притом только в самих папках а не подпапках. И окно выполняемой программы точно также тут же исчезает после выполнения

Answer (score 1):

> При попытке запуска файла двойным кликом по нему приложение выполняется и консольное окно тут же сворачивается.

Когда процесс, для которого было создано консольное окно, завершает свою работу, *операционная система сразу же уничтожает это окно*. Вызовом `getch()` вы просто «замораживаете» программу в ожидании введённого символа, отсрочивая тем самым её завершение.

---

Как это происходит? При запуске программы загрузчик PE EXE смотрит на значение её поля «подсистема» и, видя там значение `WINDOWS_CUI`, обращается к консольной подсистеме (`conhost.exe`) с просьбой создать окно. Затем потоки этого окна привязываются к стандартным потокам ввода-вывода. В дальнейшем `conhost` отслеживает состояние этих потоков.

Если же этот процесс запускает какие-то другие процессы и передаёт им *уже имеющиеся* дескрипторы ввода-вывода, их завершение консольную подсистему волновать не будет. **К примеру, если мы запустим `cmd`, а из него — вашу программу, то завершение этой программы к закрытию окна не приведёт**. Но если вы завершите сам `cmd` (командой `exit`, к примеру), то консоль мгновенно закроется.

***P. S.:*** Мне неизвестны мотивы подобного поведения, ровно как и причины невозможности принудительного вывода фразы *«Программа завершила свою работу. Нажмите любую клавишу для закрытия окна»* силами консольной подсистемы. Просто примем это как данное.

Comment: И как это поясняет описанное ТС поведение "двойным кликом они не открываются, но открываются тройным"?

Comment: @Harry, не понял насчёт тройного щелчка. В Windows же стандартно только одинарный и двойной существуют, разве нет? Возможно, у автора вопроса [стоит какая-то приблуда](http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows7/thread951982.html), и он что-то недоговаривает.

Comment: Вот и я о том же!

Comment: Тройной клик, после двух кликов окно пропадает, но ещё один быстрый клик после второго фиксирует окно

Comment: Arhad, вы написали что "К примеру, если мы запустим cmd, а из него — вашу программу, то завершение этой программы к закрытию окна не приведёт" Это не так, если я запускаю свою программку из командной строки то окно исполняемого приложения появляется на долю секунды и тут же испаряется